# How to remove the value before the cursor - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cursor-position

I created a phone with React that stores the numbers in an `input` whether you press the keys or if you use the keyboard.

The phone works fine, but pressing the delete button or the backspace key always eliminates the last value in the chain.

I need the button and the backspace key to delete the value before the cursor position. If the position is 3 I want the buttons to eliminate the number 2 in the chain, if it is 5 that eliminates the 4 ... How to remove the value before the cursor?

**Edit**:
I fix my problem thanks to @Seba99. This is the final code:

**My phone component :**

```
class Telefono extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numberClicked: '',
            inputContent: [],
            currentKey: '',
        };
        this.deleteClickNumber = this.deleteClickNumber.bind(this);
    }

    deletePrevNumber(){
        var string = this.state.inputContent.split("");
        var ctl = document.getElementById('inputTelephone');
        var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
        var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
        string.splice((startPos - 1), 1);
        this.setState({
            inputContent: string.join(''),
            numberClicked: string.join(''),
        })
    }

    deleteClickNumber(evObject){
        this.change = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                addClickedBottoms: '',
            })
        }, 300)
        this.setState({
            currentKey: evObject.keyCode
        });
        if(this.state.addClickedBottoms === ''){
            this.setState({
                addClickedBottoms: 'clicked',
            })            
        }

        if (this.state.inputContent !== ''){
            this.deletePrevNumber();
        }  
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="pad sb-content">
                <div className="dial-pad">
                    <div className="phoneString">
                        <input type="text" ref="inputTelephone" value={this.state.inputContent.toString()} onChange={this.handleKeyPress} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="digits">
                        <Numbers 
                            numbers={this.state.numbers} 
                            letters={this.state.letters}
                            addClicked={this.state.addClicked}  
                            updateNumber={this.updateNumber}
                            addClickedBottoms={this.state.addClickedBottoms}
                            deleteClickNumber={this.deleteClickNumber}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="digits">
                        <div className="dig call"><Icon icon="telefono" className='ico-telefono'/><span>LLAMAR</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my delete button in my Numbers Component

```
<div onClick={this.props.deleteClickNumber}>
  <Icon icon="borrar" className='ico-borrar'/>
</div>``
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `slice(0,-1)` always delete the last element in your array ...

**As of [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) :**

> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(2,-1) extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.

You should have a look at the [s**P**lice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which deletes the number of element you want at the selected index :

```
this.state.inputContent.splice(IndexOfTheCursor, 1);
this.setState({
     inputContent: this.state.inputContent
})
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for taking too long to respond. I've updated the code with your changes and I get the following error: this.state.inputContent.splice is not a function

Comment: Well, well, at least do you understand what you're doing ? my code shouldn't be just copy/pasted in your project it needs some modifications ... So as to set the value of the parameter I called `IndexOfTheCursor` with the right value ...

Comment: I try to understand what you are doing. I think it did not work because "splice" needs an array and not a string ... I modified it but I still do not detect IndexOfTheCursor, it gives undefined. Right now if i clicked removes the entire array and not just one element

Comment: inputContent is a String ? Why initialize it like this then ? : `inputContent: []`, then you're transforming it in the render : `this.state.inputContent.toString()` and in the `deletePrevNumber` function you're doing a strange stuff `var string = [this.state.inputContent];` ... You decide but keep the type of that variable the same in the whole code ! And btw IndexOfTheCursor is still undefined because you don't pass it to the call here : `if (this.state.inputContent !== ''){this.deletePrevNumber();}`

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the incovenience. I don't know if my solution is the best solution but my code works. If you think you can do it better, I'd love to know. Thanks again

Comment: Well mixing up react and `document.getElementById` is surely not the best option :) Take a look at the the ref with react : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
You could then, have access to the `selectionStart` of the input with `this.myRefName.current.selectionStart`

Comment: Ok, that will do. Thanks